# Isolation Level Change in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, transaction-isolation

I have a MySQL 5.7 installed on my system which is set with default transaction isolation level "REPEATABLE-READ". My scenario requires "READ-COMMITTED". So I changed the isolation level in the configuration file so that I can have "READ-COMMITTED" as default.

Yes, on adding it to configuration file, I can see isolation level was changed at global level but it remains "REPEATABLE-READ" at session level. I think anything that got changed in the file should be set across global and session levels as soon as I restarted the server. But this isn't changing.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: How are you connecting to the db? Isn't your script/library setting the session variables upon connect?

Comment: @Marki555 No, they don't. I just want to know why the values are not changing when I edited the configuration file

Comment: If `show global variables like 'tx_isolation';` shows correct value, then your config is working fine. You can also check with `mysql --verbose --help|grep isolation` - it will show you what value mysqld uses when starting up.

Comment: @Marki555 yes it does. But if I execute `show session variables like 'tx_isolation';` for a new session, I see "REPEATABLE-READ" by default. Can't we change this?

Comment: Does it happen also when connecting via mysql command-line client?

Comment: @Marki555 No! It happens when connected via Workbench only. Through command line it shows READ-COMMITTED in both session and global levels.

Comment: So some settings in Workbench are causing it to set the session variable upon connect.

Answer (score 0):

This following set query working for me in both **`session`** and **`global`** also.

> SET GLOBAL tx_isolation='READ-COMMITTED'

Again when I check the level using the following query it will return the updated value.

> SELECT @@global.tx_isolation,@@tx_isolation;

I hope this will help.